# How do I use proguard with 3DR Services?

Tags: android-proguard, dronekit-android

When I build my App using proguard, I get the following message:

> **Install 3DR Services!**
>
> 3DR Services must be installed on the device to use this app

However, 3DR Services is installed on my phone. Since it works without proguard, I assume it is removing some required classes.

How should I configure proguard to use DroneKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is the best solution, but I could make it work using the following rules:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.common.api.*
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
-keep class com.o3dr.** { *; }
```